# fixed position floating button to right side of page irrespective of scrollbar on parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a div which is floating to the right side of page. This div has a parent div which has scrollbar instead of having scroll on body.I tried applying position fixed on div which I want to float right all the time but when scrollbar appears on page it overlaps on it.

I want this div to adjust when scrollbar appears.

```
.scrollbar {
                width: 100%;
                height: 600px;
                overflow: auto;
                position: relative;
            }
            .innerDiv {
                height: 900px;
            }
            .floatingBtn {
                background: #000;
                color: #fff;
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
                width: 40px;
                right: 0;
                top: 80px;
                position: fixed;
            }
```

Thanks for reading. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqd9u87k/2/)

Comment: Just use right:40px in your .floatingBtn , so that it will not overlap ,

Comment: @L-X: Adding 40px will solve problem when scrollbar appears but what if we do not have scrollbar on page, again we need to remove this extra 40px

Comment: you can create a separate class .hasScrollbar{margin-right:40px;} and apply this class to the div if you have scrollbar otherwise remove it

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind it is, that when scroll-bar comes in, it is considered as div's width. What i mean is if your div width is `100px` so it would have actually around `85px`**(div space)** + `15px`**(scroll-bar)**

So if your **div has scroll-bar** then **width = div(content space) + scroll-bar**.

Check this out:

In below demo there are two `div's` both has same `width` i.e. `width:150px;`. But you can see the difference one is with scroll-bar and other is not.

```css
.div1, .div2 {
    display:block;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#333;
    color:#eee;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.div2 {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now talking about **your issue**. It considers the `right:0px` along with scroll-bar as part of that `div`.

So **just for explanation** i have **added JQuery** in below solution, use it only if you want.

```js
//Find Total Width of .scrollbar Div.
var totalWidth = $(".scrollbar").outerWidth();
alert("Total Width of Div is : " + totalWidth);

//Find Width of .scrollbar Div without scrollbar in it.
var divWidth = $('.scrollbar')[0]['clientWidth'];
alert("Width of Div Without Scroll-Bar is : " + divWidth);

// So now calculating the width of scrollbar.
var scrollWidth = totalWidth - divWidth;
alert("Width of scrollbar is : " + scrollWidth);
```

```css
body {
     overflow: hidden;
     margin:0px;
 }
 .scrollbar {
     margin:0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 600px;
     overflow: auto;
     position: relative;
 }
 .innerDiv {
     margin:0px;
     height: 900px;
 }
 .floatingBtn {
     background: #000;
     color: #fff;
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
     width: 40px;
     right: 15px; /* From JQuery we know scroll bar width is 17px but still reducing it 2px*/
     top: 80px;
     position: fixed;
 }
 .btnContainer {
     /*position: fixed;*/
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollbar">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <div class="btnContainer">
            <div class="floatingBtn">Button Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle : DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zqd9u87k/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, appreciate your jq code but I am looking for  css solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: scrallbar]

use *right:30px;*.
You have used extreme *right:0;* and used *position:fixed;*, so it will take extreme right.